# Improve performance for sparse tensor contraction

Tags: python, performance, tensor

I have been recenty working on a tensor contraction code where I am experiencing very slow performance times. The main thing to understand is that the tensor considered is "sparse", and therefore most of its entries are zero. In addition, this is a dtype=numpy.complex128 for the arrays considered. My tensor is 4D + 1D, with the 1D representing the arrays of type complex and array size N~1000. In order to avoid having memory issues, I have implemented the code using "key assignment" method, that is, each element of the tensor has a key associated ( 1,2,3,4 ) where at the same time, indices 1,2,3,4 are "multi-valued" indices, that can take three different values (integers as well). For example, one possible key of a non-zero entry could be:

```
                             key = ( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 )
```

All keys are **unique,** but because of the problem I am considering, relations between  key values hold and therefore, it is important to have all the integers within a single key combination. This means that one can further reduce the number of elements contributing by imposing conditions over a pair of keys, for example:

```
            np.abs( key_1[0] - key_[2] ) <=3 ---> non-zero entries must satisfy this condition (AS AN EXAMPLE, NOT THE ACTUAL CASE)
```

To each key, a Numpy array of length N is associated. My code needs to perform the following summation to contract the tensor:

```
                     A_{ 1,2,3,4 } = sum_{5,6,7,8} B_{ 1,2,7,5 } C_{ 5,6,7,8 } D_{8,6,3,4}
```

where B,C,D are, for a single value of the keys specified, numpy arrays of length N~1000.

Remember each index 1,2,.. is multivalued, so actually a multi-index. I have the following code implemented, for example to calculate the key (1,2,3,4) element for A on the left:

```
def contraction_func( data_object, key=(1,2,3,4) ):
   
    A_keys  = data_object.get_left_keys()       # A 2D numpy array containing the keys by rows,i.e. 
                                                # gamma_p_keys = np.array( [ [1,2,3,4,... ],
                                                #                             [4,4,6,7,... ], ...etc
                                                #                            ]  )
                                                # where a single row has 12 integers in my example

    A_array = data_object.get_left_array()   # to each row of left_keys, corresponds a row here
                                                # with N elements along axis=1

    C_dict   = data_object.get_C_dict()       # this gives the object C defined above as a dictionary
                                              # with the keys given by combinations of (5,6,7,8)        

    # since for example, key =(1,2,3,4) --> np.array([ 0, -1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7,9, -1, 0, 2, -2 ])
    multi_index_1p = key[0:3]
    multi_index_2p = key[3:6]
    multi_index_1  = key[6:9]
    multi_index_2  = key[9:]  

    total_indices  = len( multi_index_1p )        
    aux            = np.concatenate( ( multi_index_1, multi_index_2 )  )   
         
    a = ( A_keys[ :, 2*total_indices:3*total_indices ] == multi_index_1  ).all( axis=1 ) 
    b = ( A_keys[ :, 3*total_indices: ] == multi_index_2  ).all( axis=1 )             
 
    mask = np.multiply( (a,b ) )
    
    A_keys_filtered_right  = A_keys[ mask ]  
    A_array_filtered_right = A_array [ mask ]  

    a = ( A_keys[ :, 0:total_indices ] == multi_index_1p  ).all( axis=1 ) 
    b = ( A_keys[ :, total_indices:2*total_indices ] == multi_index_2p ).all( axis=1 )             
 
    mask = np.multiply( (a,b ) )

    A_keys_filtered_left  = A_keys[ mask ]  
    A_array_filtered_left = A_array [ mask ] 
     
    # the very time consuming part I guess..

    keys_product = np.array( [ np.concatenate( (x[0], x[1] ) ) for x in product( 
                                                                  A_keys_filtered_left  , 
                                                                  A_keys_filtered_right   )                                                                         
                                                                                                       
                                ], dtype=np.int32  )
    
    product_array = np.array( [ np.multiply( x[0], x[1] ) for x in product( 
                                                                   A_array_filtered_left , 
                                                                   A_array_filtered_right ) ] )
        

    
    s_keys = np.concatenate( ( keys_product[ :, 6:9 ], keys_product[:, 12:15] ), axis=1)
    g_keys = np.concatenate( ( keys_product[ :, 9:12 ], keys_product[:,15:18 ], axis=1 )    
    s_g_keys = list( map( tuple, np.concatenate( (g_keys,s_keys), axis = 1 ) ) )

    aux_array           = np.array( [ C_dict[ x ] for x in s_g_keys ] ) 
    aux                 = np.multiply( aux_array, product_array )

    del conv_array, gamma_product_array   

    solution_conv       = aux.sum( axis=0 )    


    return solution_conv
```

The problem scales very fast with added complexity, i.e., when the total number of keys representing non-zero entries is much larger. I would be interested to do this for sizes of typically ~ 10^5 keys of (1,2,3,4). What I find is that for a single value of (1,2,3,4), too many terms contribute to the rhs of the contraction. But my guess is that the lookup of the keys is being very expensive, any ideas on how to improve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: The computation of `keys_product` and `product_array` may be faster using numba. For the computation of `aux_array`, it is a bit more complex. If I understand correctly what you said, `C_dict` should contains small keys, no? It would be great if you could provide a [minimal working example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that use `contraction_func`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! Indeed with Numba the products of keys and the array prove to be around 10 times faster! The C is a dict with 12-integer tuple keys, and for each key, an ndarray of size N is stored. I will try to upload a minimal example of the code when possible.